# Vue Не работает фильтр в поле input

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Сделал фильтр для фильтрации ввода чисел, но чего-то не хватает.
Подскажите, почему не работает фильтр в поле input.

На странице он нормально работает:

```
<form action="" id="calc">
<input type="text" v-model="test" style="text-align: right">
<p>Model value : {{ test | numFilter }}</p>
</form>

    Vue.filter('numFilter', function (value) {
            return value.replace(/[^\d.]*/g, '')
                .replace(/([.])[.]+/g, '$1')
                .replace(/^[^\d]*(\d+([.]\d{0,5})?).*$/g, '$1');
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#calc',
  data: {
     test: ''
  }
});
```

[Ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/_igor_/pen/JwJMxW)

Когда пытаюсь применить его к полю input, даже поле не выводиться:

```
<form action="" id="calc">
<input type="text" v-model="test | numFilter" style="text-align: right">
</form>
```

[Ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/_igor_/pen/NegXZm)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Two-Way-Filters-replaced

Comment: А разве можно писать в то, что использует фильтр?

Answer (score 2):

Директива `v-model` предназначена для двусторонней связки элемента с переменной - вводите текст в поле и директива присваивает результат в переменную `test`. А вы указали `"test | numFilter"` выражение вместо имени переменной, это не работает.
Регулярное выражение вам не поможет, вам нужно создать свою пользовательскую директиву, которую нужно повесить на input для обрабатывания ввода.

[Пример посмотрите здесь](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xmrQEQ)

Пример не является решением, только описывает способ.

Или же можно использовать уже готовый компонент:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-input-number